# Time series data with a independent variable

Tags: time-series, python

I'm working on a time series data in python, which has sales at a day level. As expected, there a few peaks at holidays and long weekends. I would like to add a new binary class variable "Holiday" '1/0'. The values of the new variable change from year to year as the holiday calendar changes

I would like to use this new variable in my time series sales forecast to improve the prediction.

Could anyone please explain how I approach this problem or point me to relevant resources. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what kind of model you want to use to predict the time series, but one method of doing it might be to use a SARIMA model with exogenous dependent variables.

See this blog post for some more details https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-methods-in-python-cheat-sheet/